# My modal view does not rotate

Tags: ios, view, orientation, modal-dialog

I encounter an issue with a modal view display. My first view rotate very well. The controller of the modal view implements the "ShouldAutorotationToInterfaceRotation" method but when I rotate the device or simulator the modal view doesn't rotate.

I've added some comments to check if the first view detects the rotation events instead of the modal view but no, it doesn't get the event.

Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to subscribe to NSNotificationCenter to receive rotation events for your modal view. Then, if you want to keep the modal view orientated correctly relative to the bottom view, one solution would be to transform the view. Here's one implementation:

Put this in the **viewDidLoad** and save the original orientation as an angle:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

int initialOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (initialOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    initialAngle = 0.0;
else if (initialOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    initialAngle = 90.0;
else if (initialOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    initialAngle = 180.0;
else if (initialOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    initialAngle = 270.0;

currentAngle = initialAngle;
```

Then define the function **orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification** with code to rotate correctly relative to the initial orientation:

```
int newOrientation = [[notification object] orientation];
if (newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    desiredAngle = 0.0;
else if (newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    desiredAngle = 90.0;
else if (newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    desiredAngle = 180.0;
else if (newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    desiredAngle = 270.0;

if(desiredAngle != currentAngle)
{
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * (-desiredAngle+initialAngle) / 180.0);    
    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
    [[self releaseView] setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, rotate)];
}
currentAngle = desiredAngle;
```